# Copy data from view to a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I created a table `DBA_DATA_FILES_HIST` to store all the info from `DBA_DATA_FILES` view. When I run the following query, i get an error that the table `DBA_DATA_FILES` does not exist. I'm using Oracle.

```
SELECT *
INTO DBA_DATA_FILES_HIST
FROM view DBA_DATA_FILES;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO DBA_DATA_FILES_HIST
SELECT * FROM DBA_DATA_FILES;
```

This is valid syntax for Oracle to insert result of select. It is based on assumpion you have same columns in your table as in `DBA_DATA_FILES`

Comment: worked like a charm. Thank you. I must of misread something at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Comment: @user3508766 This is not Oracle syntax. So information on home page of the tutorial is wrong that "Our SQL tutorial will teach you how to use SQL to access and manipulate data in: MySQL, SQL Server, Access, Oracle, Sybase, DB2, and other database systems." Not every RDBMS implement standard same way

Comment: @user3508766 For Oracle please use Oracle doc like this one: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you insert records into a table, it's how you load data into a collection.

Instead use:

```
INSERT INTO DBA_DATA_FILES_HIST
SELECT * FROM DBA_DATA_FILES;
```

Comment: @user3508766: do not use w3fools that site is full of errors.